# Magento 2 add custom columns in export

Tags: magento2, grid, sales-order, export

I created some columns in sales order grid like product SKUS, It is visible in grid column as well,

But while I am export using export button, CSV return blank columns for SKUS.

Any one have idea then please share.

Comment: You have to add the column to **sales_order_grid** table.